# Cannot read image using cv2.imread()

Tags: python, ubuntu, computer-vision, opencv

I am trying to read an image and show it using `OpenCV` in Ubuntu, But for some reason it doesn't works. The file I am reading is placed in the same directory where the code resides but still it doesn't works. Can anybody tell me whats going on, Thank you

**Error**

```
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 10, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

**code.py**

```
img = cv2.imread('sample1.jpg')
print(img)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
```

Comment: The error message says that file isn't a valid JPEG: either the width or height is not greater than zero. What does the `file` program say it is? If your system has ImageMagick you can identify many images with the `identify` program, eg `identify sample1.jpg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, no image has been loaded as `print(img)` printed None, thus you cannot use cv2.imshow on a None object.

```
img = cv2.imread('sample1.jpg')
if img != None:
     cv2.imshow('image', img)
```

You could also check if there is a file by using:

```
import os
os.path.isfile('sample1.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either:

1. Absolute path which is full path:

   `img = cv2.imread('/home/jacob/Escritorio/11/1.jpg')`
2. Relative path which is parent directory, where your "code.py" and image is located.

   `img = cv2.imread('../1.jpg')`

The two dots ".." symbolize parent directory of your file - directory where your file resides